# SAP HANA:- Using calculation views(on top of table) instead of referring to direct table in procedures for better performance

Tags: hana

Am new to SAP HANA, someone suggested me to use views instead of tables for better performance in store procedures is that true. I mean creating calculation view on top of table and use view in procedure instead of table.

Even view will refer underlying table how come it will improve performance please guide.

They say that if we use a table in procedure and any query(other session) is fetching data from same table will cause blocking which might impact performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s not an accurate statement. The straight intermediate projection won’t add any “speed-up”.
And using views within a table function or procedure does not block other processes from reading from it at the same time.

Your colleagues may want to check those assumptions e.g.  by using PlanViz trace or EXPLAIN PLAN.

Comment: Regarding "using views within a table function or procedure does not block other processes from reading from it at the same time", assumption is using table in procedure has something related to blocking instead view will help here. So they are suggesting to use view instead of table that is view on top of table.

Comment: I answered this already - their assumptions can be checked (and shown wrong) by using the appropriate trace and analysis tools.

Comment: Thank you for the info, Iet me do my home work and come back.